# Physical delete a model which is enabled softdelete in laravel5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, soft-delete

I am using `SoftDeletes` for a model in Laravel5.

But in some cases (Keeping history is not useful),I want to do physical delete (Removing row from table)instead of `softDelete`.

```
    class PaymentInvoices extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

Is there any method for forcing physical delete?

Comment: As a fallback, there's always `DB::raw`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course there is. Use `forceDelete` method instead of just `delete`.

Keep in mind, `forceDelete` is only available if you use the `SoftDeletes` trait.

Example

```
$instance->delete() //This is a soft delete
$instance->forceDelete() // This is a 'hard' delete
```

More info [here](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models)  (scroll down to **Permanently Deleting Models**)

Comment: `delete()` justs updates the `deleted_at` field to the deleted time. Thus that record is ignored in subsequent retrievals through Laravel (Eloquent API). But if you use raw select or other direct database access, surprise - it's there.

Comment: Of course it's there, Laravel just returns all the records that have
`deleted_at` equal to `NULL`. 

There is no magic happening :)

Check how the eloquent builder works [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletingScope.php)

Comment: Thanks @Harry-Geo for the clarification and reference. I was speaking figuratively just to point out the pitfall of using mixed access including raw queries (not using Eloquent models) on the tables without filtering out records with non NULL `deleted_at` field value - which would return all records, including the soft deleted ones.